# Blastx: from gi to description

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-sequencing, gene-annotation

I have done a blastx and use the outfmt 6 option, because I want to work in the tables format. When I do this I get subject ids of the type

> sp|Q7XJS0|ASHR1_ARATH, sp|Q39547|CUCM1_CUCME,

et cetera.

However, in this blastx output format I cannot find any option that will give me the descriptions of these blast hits.
Could anyone advice me how I can link these subject ids with descriptions of the sequences, e.g., 'amino acid transporter ANTL1-like'? I'd be much obliged.

j

Comment: Does the fasta/gb file from which this BLAST database was built have these descriptions in the header? If not take a look here: https://www.biostars.org/p/110000/

Comment: You have to map these ids to a file that contains gene description. Usually the GTF/GFF file for that reference genome would have these descriptions.